# If $Y_i \sim N(\theta,1)$, and prior $p(\theta)$, how can we show the posterior predictive approximately is $N(\hat{\theta}_n, 1+\frac{1}{n})$?

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, asymptotics

If I have iid data $Y_i \sim N(\theta,1)$, and an arbitrary prior $p(\theta)$ on $\mathbb{R}$, how to show the posterior predictive approximately is $N\left(\hat{\theta}_n, 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$?

Here, $\hat{\theta}_n$ is the MLE of the data. I read in some lecture notes that the posterior predictive, which is defined by:

$$
p(y) = \int p(y|\theta)p(\theta|y_1, \ldots, y_n)d\theta
$$

has the property that the predicted obervation has the distribution of:

$$
\Theta_n + \epsilon
$$

where $\Theta_n$ follows the posterior distribution of approximately $N\left(\hat{\theta}_n,\frac{1}{n}\right)$

and that $\epsilon \sim N(0,1)$, independent of $\Theta_n$. I am not sure how to show these two results from the posterior predictive. I assumed that $\Theta_n + \epsilon \sim N\left(\hat{\theta}_n,\frac{1}{n}\right)$ approximately by the **Bernstein Von-Mises Theorem**. However, I am not sure how to get the clean sum decomposition. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Where did you get this question from? I would like to read more about it. Thanks.

Comment: I think the answer is here: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/298 if you get ride of prior part.

Comment: If $\phi(x;\mu,\sigma^2)$ is the Gaussian PDF then $$p(y) \propto \int \phi(y;\theta,1) \phi(\hat{\theta}_n;\theta,1/n) p(\theta)\,\rm{d}\theta.$$ From here, you should be able to use Laplace's approximation to get the answer.